# AVPlayer doesn't respond to commands from bluetooth device

Tags: ios, mpremotecommandcenter

My ios app uses AVQueuePlayer to play audio.

The play/pause controls work properly from Control Center and from ios lock screen, but not for commands invoked from bluetooth device. E.g., the callbacks in my app are never invoked when double-tapping airpods or other third-party bluetooth headphones.

I'm running on an iphone 8 plus device with iOS 15.

I'm using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/controlling_background_audio.

On app startup, it sets up the audio session like this:

```
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord,
                                         mode: .spokenAudio,
                                         options: [
                                            .allowBluetooth,
                                            .defaultToSpeaker
                                         ])
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
```

The app listens for play/pause events like this.

```
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { event in
print("play")
    return .success
        }
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { event in
print("pause")
    return .success
        }
commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget { event in
    print("toggleplaypause")
    return .success
}
```

Playback works correctly through all bluetooth devices. On lock screen or control center, play/pause cause "play" and "pause" to get printed. But nothing is printed when tapping airpods. (Tapping airpods works fine in any other audio app.)

Any ideas what might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Airpod controls started working when I changed the mode to `.playback`. Apparently they don't work with `.playAndRecord`. I also needed to remove the `.allowBluetooth`, which is not compatible with `.playback` mode.
For my app, since I need to both play and record, I will set the mode to `.playAndRecord` when the user needs to record, and otherwise keep it in `.playback`.